# How do I use Meteor.apply with options?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using `Meteor.call` method for invoking a function on server. It is kind of working, however it seems like result is not fully returning. (Expecting length of 250, now it returning 11, 121, something like that)
I am using async `Meteor.call`. I am guessing before server side function complete, `Meteor.call` is returning a result. I tried sync call but I'm not clearly understand the Meteor docs.

So I am trying to use `Meteor.apply()` with options. How can I use `Meteor.apply` with options? Any examples?

client.js

```
var chartData;
Template.prodSelect.events({
  'click': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var prodName = document.getElementById("productSelect").value;
    //console.log(prodName);
    Meteor.call('chartData', prodName,function(err,data){
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
      chartData = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log(data);
      createChart(chartData);
    });
  }
});
```

Tried this , but is gives error.

```
var chartData;
Template.prodSelect.events({
  'click': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var prodName = document.getElementById("productSelect").value;
    //console.log(prodName);
    Meteor.apply('chartData', prodName,{wait: true}, function(err,data){
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
      chartData = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log(data);
      createChart(chartData);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What does the method look like?

Comment: What error does it give and what does the method look like?

Answer (score 5):

Just figured this out myself. You need to pass the arguments as an array, and to specify "wait", you just pass `true` to the function. So, in your case:

`Meteor.apply('chartData', [prodName], true, function(err, result){`

Comment: The `true` that you have refers to the field options.noRetry not to the wait. See 
`Meteor.apply(name, args, [options], (Boolean), [asyncCallback])`

Answer (score 1):

In order not to receive `Malformed method invocation` error, you should pass arguments as an array.
And in addition to @robut's answer:
It's still best to see what options you are passing, thus I prefer:

```
Meteor.apply('addPost',[] ,{wait:true})
```